# queryDSL any().concat

Tags: jpa, querydsl

Please help,

How could I concat properties from oneToMany relatioship?

```
order.users.any().firstName
    .concat(order.users.any().lastName)
    .containsIgnoreCase(request.fullName)
```

This gives strange exeption:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "user4_"
```

Comment: How does the resulting JPQL and/or SQL look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got this working when making two way mapping and using JPASubQuery.

```
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
...
JPASubQuery from = new JPASubQuery()
                    .from(QOrderUnit.orderUnit)
                    .where(QOrderUnit.orderUnit.orderBatch.eq(orderBatch).
                            and(QOrderUnit.orderUnit.firstName.concat(" ").concat(QOrderUnit.orderUnit.lastName)
                                    .containsIgnoreCase(orderRequest.getOwners())));
builder.and(from.exists());
```